# Convert decimal currency to an integer

Tags: c#, fixed-point

I have some code that is used to convert a decimal currency to an integer with precision being a function of which currency is being converted.

This code is more of a "brute-force" method to do the conversion and just doesn't feel right to me. Is there a better way to achieve the result?

```
    public static int CurrencyToInt(decimal amount, string currencyCode)
    {
        var precision = 0;

        currencyCode = currencyCode?.ToUpperInvariant();

        if (new[] {
            "BHD", "IQD", "JOD", "KWD", "LYD", "OMR", "TND"
        }.Contains(currencyCode))
        {
            precision = 3;
        }
        else if (new[] {
            "AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG", "AOA", "ARS", "AUD", "AWG", "AZN", "BAM", "BBD", "BDT", "BGN", "BMD",
            "BND", "BOB", "BRL", "BSD", "BTN", "BWP", "BZD", "CAD", "CDF", "CHF", "CNY", "COP", "CRC", "CUC", "CUP",
            "CZK", "DKK", "DOP", "DZD", "EGP", "ERN", "ETB", "EUR", "FJD", "FKP", "GBP", "GEL", "GGP", "GHS", "GIP",
            "GMD", "GTQ", "GYD", "HKD", "HNL", "HRK", "HTG", "HUF", "IDR", "ILS", "IMP", "INR", "IRR", "JEP", "JMD",
            "KES", "KGS", "KHR", "KPW", "KYD", "KZT", "LAK", "LBP", "LKR", "LRD", "LSL", "LTL", "LVL", "MAD", "MDL",
            "MKD", "MMK", "MNT", "MOP", "MUR", "MVP", "MVR", "MWK", "MXN", "MYR", "MZN", "NAD", "NGN", "NIO", "NOK",
            "NPR", "NZD", "PAB", "PEN", "PGK", "PHP", "PKR", "PLN", "QAR", "RON", "RSD", "RUB", "SAR", "SBD", "SCR",
            "SDG", "SEK", "SGD", "SHP", "SLL", "SOS", "SPL", "SRD", "STD", "SVC", "SYP", "SZL", "THB", "TJS", "TMT",
            "TOP", "TRY", "TTD", "TVD", "TWD", "TZS", "UAH", "USD", "UYU", "UZS", "VEF", "WST", "XCD", "XDR", "YER",
            "ZAR", "ZMW", "ZWD"
        }.Contains(currencyCode))
        {
            precision = 2;
        }
        else if (new[] {
            "MGA", "MRO"
        }.Contains(currencyCode))
        {
            precision = 1;
        }
        else if (new[]{
            "BIF", "BYR", "CLP", "CVE", "DJF", "GNF", "ISK", "JPY", "KMF", "KRW", "PYG", "RWF", "UGX", "VND", "VUV",
            "XAF", "XOF", "XPF"
        }.Contains(currencyCode))
        {
            precision = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown currency code " + currencyCode, nameof(currencyCode));
        }

        while (precision > 0)
        {
            amount *= 10;
            precision--;
        }

        return (int)Math.Floor(amount);
    }
```

Comment: Why not to create static Dictionary<string, int> instead?

Comment: Suggest reading up on [CultureInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [CultureInfo.NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat.aspx) in particular.  Let the framework help you.  CultureInfo includes country codes and currency symbol.

Comment: amount *= Math.Pow(10, precision);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is intentionally(?):

I would expect `CurrencyToInt(234.567m, "USD")` to return `23457`, but it returns `23456`?

---

Instead of the rather unclear if-statements it is more readable with a switch:

```
public static int CurrencyToInt(decimal amount, string currencyCode)
{
  var precision = 0;

  currencyCode = currencyCode?.ToUpperInvariant();

  switch (currencyCode)
  {
    case "BHD": case "IQD": case "JOD": case "KWD": case "LYD": case "OMR": case "TND":
      precision = 3;
      break;
    case "AED": case "AFN": case "ALL": case "AMD": case "ANG": case "AOA": case "ARS": case "AUD": case "AWG": case "AZN": case "BAM": case "BBD": case "BDT": case "BGN": case "BMD":
    case "BND": case "BOB": case "BRL": case "BSD": case "BTN": case "BWP": case "BZD": case "CAD": case "CDF": case "CHF": case "CNY": case "COP": case "CRC": case "CUC": case "CUP":
    case "CZK": case "DKK": case "DOP": case "DZD": case "EGP": case "ERN": case "ETB": case "EUR": case "FJD": case "FKP": case "GBP": case "GEL": case "GGP": case "GHS": case "GIP":
....
```

---

As stated in the comments the whole thing can be boiled down to 3 lines of code, if you use the framework:

```
public static int CurrencyToIntByCulture(decimal amount, string currencyCode)
{
  CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(currencyCode);
  int precision = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits;
  return (int)(amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision));

  // Or?: return (int)Math.Round((amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision)));
}
```

But `culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits` returns different numbers of decimals for certain cultures, so maybe you have special needs?

Comment: As to the special needs, it seems better to abstract this in a separate method anyway. Defining the precision and applying it are two different things. It doesn't matter for your example, but if it's a custom mapping, it does start to matter more. That would mean that your 3 line example would turn into a 2 line example, where `int precision = getCustomPrecision(currencyCode);`.

Comment: @Flater: You may be right, but we know to little about the context and needs. If you have to overrule some of the culture defined precisions then a separate function is appropriate for that.